failing at authentication flow with keycloak in flutter
I'm struggling to understand how correctly to configure the authentication using keycloak in flutter (currently on android)
I'm running in a docker a container of Keycloak (quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:24.0.2) on port 8080
I've opened a new realm in my keycloak server named mqtt, opened new client named mqtt-client and based on many many searches, configured it with Valid redirect URI as my app package (com.example.mqttIot://*) and set t he web origins as *
Configured a browser flow
Cookie (Alternative)
 - Auth Flow (Alternative)
   - 1st Condition Flow (Conditional)
     - Condition LoA level 1 (Required)
     - Username Password Form (Required)
   - 2nd Condition Flow (Conditional)
     - Condition LoA level 2 (Required)
     - OTP Form (Required)

Now, in the flutter app, using the openid-client package, this is what i've implemented, again, after many many searches:
Future<void> keycloakSignIn() async {
    const keycloakBaseUrlServerUrl = "http://{machineIP}:8080";
    const issuerUrl = "http://{machineIP}:8080/realms/mqtt";

    const clientId = 'mqtt-client';
    const scopes = ['openid', 'mqtt-client-dedicated'];
    const port = 8080;
    const clientSecret = 'Qh9z6sP214EIkuaorA5C4DWKtWPuoQWb';
    const redirectURL = 'com.example.mqttIot://*';
    const realmUrlSegment = 'realms/mqtt';
    const authProtocolSegment = 'protocol/openid-connect/auth';
    final state = generateRandomString(40);
    final nonce = generateRandomString(40);
    final codeVerifier = generateRandomString(64);
    final codeChallenge = getCodeChallenge(codeVerifier);
    try {
      final uri = Uri.parse(
        '$keycloakBaseUrlServerUrl/$realmUrlSegment/$authProtocolSegment'
        '?client_id=$clientId'
        '&redirect_uri=$redirectURL'
        '&scope=profile'
        '&state=$state'
        '&nonce=$nonce'
        '&response_type=code'
        '&code_challenge=$codeChallenge'
        '&code_challenge_method=S256',
      );

      final redirectUri = Uri.parse(redirectURL);
      logger.logWithTag("URI", uri.toString());
      logger.logWithTag("Redirect URI", redirectUri.toString());
      final issuer = await Issuer.discover(Uri.parse(issuerUrl));
      logger.logWithTag("Issuer Metadata", issuer.metadata.toString());

      final client = Client(issuer, clientId, clientSecret: clientSecret);

      urlLauncher(String url) async {
        if (await canLaunchUrl(uri)) {
          logger.log("can launch uri: $uri");
          await launchUrl(uri, mode: LaunchMode.inAppBrowserView);
        } else {
          throw 'Could not launch $uri';
        }
      }

      final authenticator = Authenticator(
        client,
        scopes: scopes,
        urlLancher: urlLauncher,
      );

      logger.log(authenticator.toString());
      await authenticator.authorize().then((value) async {
        logger.log("1, $value");

        final token = await value.getTokenResponse();
        logger.log(token.toString());
      });
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      logger.logWithTag("AuthRepository", e.toString());
    }
  }

String getCodeChallenge(String codeVerifier) =>
    base64UrlEncode(sha256.convert(utf8.encode(codeVerifier)).bytes);

in this state, when I'm trying to access the sign in flow, I'm getting this log in the docker logs:
INFO  [org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.AuthorizationEndpointChecker] (executor-thread-179) PKCE supporting Client with invalid code challenge specified in PKCE, codeChallenge = gY3SCFyJIBOnvpsqrhW1iBU-TqcF6uRi2VY2Aq66xvE=

Now i did configure in the Keycloak client Proof Key for Code Exchange Code Challenge Method as S256
Besides that, in every place that I saw examples or other issues, I've seen that the url is http://{domain}:{port}/auth/....
but the auth segmenet in the url didn't work for me at all
could someone help me with that issue?
or at least explain to me the issue?
